# Automatically determine number-of-decimals in Excel list based on data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have a list that looks like this:

```
4  
1.5  
6.333425
```

When I put a list like this into something like *ListPro*, the program understands that these are numbers (not string) and yet understands that I want them displayed at the number of decimal points I've actually inputted.

Now if I try to put the same list in Excel, it will give me:

a)

```
4.000000   
1.500000  
6.333425
```

Really annoying as now I don't know if the value was measured at exactly 4.00000 (HUGELY exact measurement) or if the margins or errors were only able to measure it at 4.

b)

```
4  
2  
6
```

Also annoying

What can I do to make it as easy as possible to enter the original list?

Ideally I don't want to have to go into each cell to set a custom number-of-decimals value, as it's more steps. Also I don't want to use a text-format as that might interfere with graphs or something later on.

Comment: you can do the whole column at once to set the number format not cell by cell.

Comment: Default behaviour of Excel with "General" number format is exactly what you need. Please eosinophil how exactly you improve your data to help understanding why default functionality doesn't work.

Comment: (1) It seems fairly obvious to me, but it might help other people understand your question if you explained how you got the (a) and (b) displays.  (2) Are you asking about having (raw input) numbers *display* as they were entered, or are you asking about letting user-created functionality in the workbook (formulas and macros) be able to access the input precision?  (3) Does your workbook do math (in formulas and/or macros)? How should 4+6.333425 be displayed?  (4) Are you willing to consider a solution in which numbers are entered as text and then processed?

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably a setting in your Excel sheet or your Template even.

Normally, Excel shows only the number of digits entered, and does *not* add trailing zeros, unless you explicitly format a cell to do so. What you describe (`4` becoming `4.000000`) means that the cell is set to a format with fixed 6 digits behind the decimal point (`0.000000` or something more complex even). If you use the format 'General', this will not happen.

1. select all your cells and change the format to 'General'. All should be fine.
2. find out where the fixed-digits format code comes from, and fix your template (in the same way - set to 'General')

Comment: Aha, I was under the impression "General" would be treated as something like a string, thus look good but not sort well and cause problems with graphics and stuff. but you seem to be right that General is suitible/recommended for numbers (as long as I don't accidentally put a character in there)